# Passing changed state to props and props are not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have problem passing updated state through react-router-dom element **NavLink**.

Here is sample code of component 1:

```
...
this.state = {
   toggle: true;
}

this.handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {toggle: !prevState.toggle});
}

...

render() {
    { toggle } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>{toggle}</div>
        <NavLink to={{pathname: "component2path", toggle}}>
            <div role="presentation" onClick={this.handleClick}>click</div>
        </NavLink>
    );
}
```

So after clicking i can see change in div that is toggling true/false.

Here is sample code of component 2:

```
ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    { toggle } = this.props.location;
    { toggleOld } = prevProps.location;
    
    console.log(toggle,toggleOld); //this never change

    //i want to achieve this
    if(toggle === toggleOld) {
       doAction(); //do something;
    }
}
```

Problem is that it looks like i cannot reflect state change in props.

Can someone help? Im bit stucked with this for too long.

Comment: Are you simply trying to send some state with the route push to the new path?

Comment: yes actually that is what i found, how props are sent via react-router-dom navLink

Answer (score 0):

The `Link`'s `to` prop object form accepts only 4 properties: `pathname`, `search`, `hash`, and `state`.

[Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

```
<NavLink
  to={{
    pathname: "component2path", 
    state: {
      toggle, // <-- pack value into state object
    },
  }}
>
  <div role="presentation" onClick={this.handleClick}>click</div>
</NavLink>
```

Extract them from `props.location.state`

```
ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    { toggle } = this.props.location.state;
    { toggleOld } = prevProps.location.state;
    
    console.log(toggle,toggleOld); //this never change

    //i want to achieve this
    if(toggle === toggleOld) {
       doAction(); //do something;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for try, but actually it still passess false. it is not reflecting state. After click in first div i can see true. But in prevProps and props is still false.

Comment: @MartinFric Isn't the initial `state.toggle` value true, so receiving false is correct? Or is your scenario not quite as laid out in your snippets? Is component 1 still mounted to update state when the navigation to new path occurs?

Comment: yes, actually it is menu. It is mounted all time long app is present

Comment: sorry... i mean in prevprops and props is true... i was just out of my mind

Comment: @MartinFric No worries. Ok, so the issue is likely an order issue between react state updating and navigating to a new path. My guess is the event propagation up the VDOM places the state update in the event queue while the navigation is a synchronous call. I think your code navigates before it has the correct updated state value. The quick fix is to simply forward in route state what you expect the next state to be, i.e. `{ pathname: '...', state: { toggle: !toggle } }`.

Comment: and is there a way to call redirect in state update function explicitly?

Comment: Ok. I think i see... So prop change based on state update is not bubbling like in normal structured components. here props comes only during redirection?

Comment: @MartinFric Like `history.replace(path, [state])` https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history? You could use the `this.setState` second argument callback function, or add another "linkClicked" flag and use a lifecycle function to handle it, but IMO this adds unnecessary complexity. You basically want to click the link and do (1) update component 1 state, and (2) navigate to component 2 with toggled value. Like I said, it may just be easier/quicker to send a toggled state value when navigating and then react can update state when it does. Getting out of synch is still possible though.

Comment: how do you mean that lifecycle function handler for flag?

Comment: @MartinFric I probably shouldn't have mentioned it since I think it takes your semantic DOM behavior in the wrong direction, but basically prevent default and stop propagation on the click event so the navigation doesn't occur, let the click handler toggle state ***and*** set a "clicked" flag true, then in `componentDidUpdate` check if "clicked" flag is true and set "clicked" flag false ***and*** `history.push(path, [state])` with the correct state payload. I'm still trying to understand why you basically have an onClick handler and a link working together, it's just going to have issues.

Comment: actually NavLink has no onClick handler i think. i need to inform that i actually clicked on that link and send proper state. Or every time i click, to object is refreshed?